# What are the available chart types for the Azure DevOps chartimages API?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Azure DevOps has REST API endpoints to get chart images [per iteration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/chartimages/get-iteration-chart-image?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) or for [multiple iterations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/chartimages/get-iterations-chart-image?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).

Both require a `name` parameter which allows to ask for a specific chart type.

The official documentation (links above) gives an example for per-iteration requests, a **burndown** chart. For the multiple-iteration requests, the example given is a **velocity** chart.

The documentation strongly suggests there are other chart types available, but I was not able to find a list of existing chart types anywhere.

Would anyone have an idea of what other options there are?